# Is there any way to apply linear transformations on a vector other than matrix multiplication?

Tags: linear-regression, statistical-ai, linear-algebra

I am trying to optimize the cost function calculation in regression analysis using a non-matrix multiplication based approach.

More specifically, I have a point $x = (1, 1, 2, 3)$, to which I want to apply a linear transformation $n$ times. If the transformation is denoted by a $4 \times 4$ matrix $A$, then the final transformation would be given by $A^n * x$.

Given that matrix multiplication can computational expensive, is there a way we can speed up the computation, assuming we would need to run multiple iterations of this simulation?

Comment: Singular value decomposition might help.

Answer (score 1):

You can sometimes exploit the structure of your matrix to perform faster matrix multiplication. For example, if your matrix is [sparse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) (or dense), there are algorithms that exploit this fact.

In your case, you can actually compute $A^n$ in less time than $\mathcal{O}(n^3$). For example, have a look at [this question at CS SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/4998/20691) and [this one at Stack Overflow (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12311869/3924118). Note that the provided solutions may not be numerically stable, so I am not suggesting you use them.

Moreover, if you perform your operations on the GPU, they could be faster in practice. See e.g. [this question at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51344018/3924118) and [this one at SciComp SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/5372/9925).